# unable to share module

Tags: python, module, python-3.3

I am trying to distribute modules. I am just new in this section
after installing my folder Python33 in `C:\`, I add this on path, create a folder booklist and write following two files; `booklist.py`, where I write

```
def book list(list):
for each_value in list:
    `if isinstance(each_value,list):
        booklist(each_value)
    else:print(each_value)`**
```

and `setup.py` where I write

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup( 
    name='booklist',
    version='1.0.0',
    py_modules=['booklist'],
    author='samiha',
    author_email='samihasultana@gmail.com',
)
```

open command prompt in `booklist` folder,
write

```
<stdin> line 1
  setup.py `sdist`
                ^
syntax error:invalid syntax,
```

get error file

```
    <stdin> line 1
  setup.py `sdist`
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax,
```

Can you explain why?

Comment: Note: don't use `list` as a variable name.  When you write `isinstance(each_value, list)`, that `list` is your sequence, not the builtin type.

Answer (score 2):

`setup.py` is not a command you put in the python interpreter. Run it in your terminal shell or Windows command console with:

```
C:\Python33\bin\python setup.py sdist
```